# How to get the last 'n' transactions in solana.py?

Tags: transactions, python, solana.py

I am currently working on a Shop based which accepts Solana as the form of currency, I want to know the details of last n transactions on my wallet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few APIs that might help you

https://api.magiceden.dev/#ae26fcd6-cff6-496b-8fae-d93f6287711f (Magic Eden Only)

https://public-api.solscan.io/docs/#/Account/get_account_transactions

https://docs.solana.fm/v3-api-reference/account

Answer (score 1):

To fetch last 'n' tx signatures and info about them:

```
from solana.rpc.api import Client, Pubkey
solana_client = Client("...")

res = solana_client.get_signatures_for_address(
    Pubkey.from_string('WALLET ADDRESS'),
    limit = 100 # Specify how much last transactions to fetch
)
```

The max limit is 1000, however you can fetch more signatures by passing the first transaction's signature as `before` argument.

To then get the parsed transaction:

```
solana_client.get_transaction(
    res.value[1].signature, 
    'jsonParsed', 
    max_supported_transaction_version=0
)
```